# Changing the type of Exception thrown by Camunda

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-transactions, camunda, bpmn

[image: You can see the picture of my sub process, which gets an error during the send Payment stage and should return the appropriate exception message that I wrote, but the exception message itself returns Camunda.]I have a method that is called during a process by camunda.
I have put a mechanism in this method to show the appropriate error message to the user if an error occurs.
But when this method hits an error, instead of displaying my proper error message, it throws this error message:
Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only
In fact, camunda converts my type of error, which is a RuntimeException, to UnexpectedRollbackException.

You can see the picture of my sub process, which gets an error during the send Payment stage and should return the appropriate exception message that I wrote, but the exception message itself returns Camunda.

Does anyone have an idea to solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: why not catch the UnexpectedRollbackException, and rethrow as a RuntimeException? or try to map the UnexpectedRollbackException to your message

Comment: for more information please edit your question and put your BPMN diagram

Comment: @Stultuske Thank you for your guidance
The UnexpectedRollbackException message doesn't help me try to rethrow it or map it
This is a message throw by camunda.
My problem is that the appropriate exception that I wrote inside the method to be thrown is lost or destroyed and is no longer displayed to the user.

Comment: `UnexpectedRollbackException` looks like an exception coming from the infrastructure layer while showing the appropriate error message to the user is a presentation concern. Without knowing much about camunda and how you utilize it,  there should be at least one or more layers in between the presentation and the infrastructure like service, domain etc. In a perfect world, I would catch the  `UnexpectedRollbackException` in one of those layers (most likely the service), wrap and rethrow as another exception type which my `ExceptionHandler` > presentation  layers knows how to deal with it.